# Props cloned to data variable updating when data variable changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Problem: I have a prop in a Vue component.

```
props: {
  user_info: {
    type: Object,
    default() {
      return {}
    }
  }
}
```

I need to use this prop not only for read, but also to make some changes in it. But i cant change the prop, so i cloned it to a data variable

```
mounted() {
  this.clonedUserInfo = {...this.user_info}
}
```

clonedUserInfo is an empty object in Data option.

But when i change clonedUserInfo, my prop user_info also changes.

So is there any way to brake this Data dependency from Props?

By the way if i am cloning not a Props but a Vuex state variables - it clones fine without changing the base State variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LODASH**

You can solve this using Lodash's CloneDeep.

```
npm i --save lodash.clonedeep

const cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');
```

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep

Docs: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

**USE A FUNCTION**

You can try this to deep clone objects:

```js
function cloneDeepWithoutLodash(src) {
  let target = {};

  for (const prop in src) {
    if (src.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if(src[prop] != null && typeof src[prop] === 'object') {
        target[prop] = cloneDeepWithoutLodash(src[prop]);
      } else {
        target[prop] = src[prop];
      }
    }
  }

  return target;
}

const source = {a: { b:2 }, c:3};
const target = cloneDeepWithoutLodash(source);

source.a.b = 100; // Lets change the source to check if target changes

console.log(source.a.b); // 100
console.log(target.a.b); // 2
```

**IMPORTANT**

Always try to avoid `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))`.

By doing this you will lose any Javascript property that has no equivalent type in JSON, like Function or Infinity. Any property that’s assigned to undefined will be ignored by JSON.stringify, causing them to be missed on the cloned object.

Also, some objects are converted to strings, like Date objects for example (also, not taking into account the timezone and defaulting to UTC), Set, Map and many others.

Comment: Any way to do that without installing any side dependencies?

Comment: Hi Anton! I edited the answer to add one deepClone function to avoid lodash's dependency. Enjoy!

Comment: kinda complicated, butt hanks a lot:)

Comment: You're welcome! You just need to: cloneDeepWithoutLodash(yourObject)

Comment: I mean the function ) usage is fine :)

Comment: Yes, its true. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way.

```
mounted() {
  this.clonedUserInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.user_info))
}
```

For now you are copying by reference. And thanks to my answer you will be copying by value.
Look at this SO answer to understand the difference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/3956205

Comment: This will only work for certain types and will not handle circular reference.

Comment: Indeed but for a normal use it works fine ! (And pretty sure `user_info` is a simple object but you never know)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But still, when i'm doing same thing with for example mapState objects/arrays - they are cloning as i expected. Whats the difference between data in props and data in state/getters?

Answer (score 1):

You are shallow copying `user_info`.

If you only have value only vars in `user_info` this will work, otherwise you'll update the original values.

You need to deep copy `user_info`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new object `clonedUserInfo` that is correct. But all objects inside of `clonedUserInfo` will be copied by reference.

Try smth like `cloneDeep` perhaps

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep